# Statistical Distributions

Tags: matlab

I work on image treatment, and I have been working on Ultrasound images to help in the diagnosis of a specific cardiac disease. I am applying statistical methods to characterize the speckle in the images. Those are the statistical distributions such as Gamma, Rayleigh, Nakagami, etc.

I am very much interested in finding MATLAB codes for the following distributions for parameter estimation:
- K
- Homodyned K
- Generalized Gamma
- Generalized Gamma Mixture Model

Your help is appreciated,
V

Comment: Have you tried to find these ones in Matlab FileExchange?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
Yes I did, I could not find parameter estimation codes.